# Fluent NuGet messed up

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nuget, nuget-package

I have a solution with several projects. I changed a couple of references for Fluent nHibernate to NuGet packages (v1.3.0.717). Recently I changed another project and added the current Fluent package, 1.2.0.712 (earlier but current) and my app will build but not run. The current version points to nHibernate v3.1.0.4 but somewhere it clashes with v3.2.9.4000 which the previous version of Fluent referenced.

```
Inner Exception
{"Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"
NHibernate, Version=3.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4"}

Exception
Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.2.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

What do I do to clean this project up and get it running again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove all NHibernate/Fluent Nhibernate related packages and run command

```
Install-Package FluentNHibernate -Version 1.3.0.717
```

It will install [correct package](http://nuget.org/packages/FluentNHibernate/1.3.0.717) for you.

For some reason this package is not marked as current version. That is why Nuget gives you old one.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that fixed the problem. I tried this but must have missed a project because I got the reverse "Trying to load 3.2.4 but 3.1.0 was found" made sure every project was set correctly.

Comment: Does this mean the fault is with the package publisher?